# Add timestamp to backup file on debian

Tags: linux, bash, timestamp, dump, database-backups

in a debian machine I'm try to add a timestamp at the end of the generated .sql file for backup.

This one is working for backup all database available in "dblist.txt" with same exact filename:

```
cat /root/dblist.txt | while read i; do /usr/sbin/plesk db dump "$i" > /root/mysql_dumps_all/"$i".sql; done
```

but if I try to add a timestamp (`date +%F.%s`) like this I get an error and no one backup is generated. What I'm missing?

```
cat /root/dblist.txt | while read i; do /usr/sbin/plesk db dump "$i" > /root/mysql_dumps_all/"$i".`date +%F.%s`.sql; done
```

Comment: What actual error message are you getting? I did a quick test using `i=foobar; touch "$i".\`date +%F.%s\`.sql; ls foobar*` gave me
`foobar.2022-09-02.1662125594.sql`just fine

Comment: How about this one?                                                                                                           cat /root/dblist.txt | while read i; do /usr/sbin/plesk db dump "$i" > /root/mysql_dumps_all/"${i}.$(date +%F.%s)".sql; done